# Run nohup and eval from python

Tags: python, bash, eval, ssh-keys, nohup

I need run two commands (from shell looks like)

```
$ eval `ssh-agent -s`
Agent pid 8631
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/user
```

**Note**: The key is in /home/user/.ssh/user and is correct

Run is as bash script works as charm:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup `eval `ssh-agent -s`` >/dev/null 2>&1 &
ssh-add ~/.ssh/$user
```

but from python I can't get working, **ssh-agent** is started but **ssh-add** returns:
*Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.*

```py
import os
os.system('nohup \'eval `ssh-agent -s`\' &')
os.system('ssh-add /home/user/.ssh/user')
```

I've tried:

```py
import os
system('nohup sh -c \'eval `ssh-agent -s`\' &')
```

same problem ssh-agent started, but somehow I can't connected

Answer (score 2):

What `os.system` does it to launch a different shell for each command. And what `` eval `ssh-agent -s` `` does is to launch a new `ssh-agent` and store in current shell some environment variables needed to communicate with it. Finally, `ssh-add` uses that variables to access the `ssh-agent` agent to add a new key to it.

So you need to execute both commands on the same shell. You can do this with a unique call to `os.system` calling both commands sequentially:

```
os.system("eval `ssh-agent -s`; ssh-add /home/user/.ssh/user")
```

Comment: Seems to working, I got:
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory

Since my private key is password protected. But when I add pexpect to fetch output and pass password I got: *pexpect.ExceptionPexpect: The command was not found or was not executable: eval.*